# Facebook SDK for unity - how to set App Id programmatically?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to use different App Ids for Facebook based on conditions and set the App Id programmatically. 
But `FB.init` method doesn't have an option for selecting the **App Id** and is using the Id which is set using the Inspector.
How can I change it in code?

Comment: For people who might wonder what's the value of this question and answer, my use case was using two separate App Ids for development and production builds. But it's not documented anywhere how to set Ids programatically (at least I hadn't found it) and Facebook Unity plugin limits you to only one app id through the inspector. So it was a very useful finding for me and I decided to share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code, and use your own `app_id`

```
Facebook.Unity.Settings.FacebookSettings.AppIds = new List<string>(new[]{ "1111_app_id_111" });
```

Then call:

```
FB.init()
```